# OSGi caches leaves newly installed bundles in INSTALLED state

Tags: osgi

I have a C++ program that loads a JVM and launches an OSGi framework. The OSGi framework is Equinox, more precisely `org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v20120830-144521.jar`.

## The Launcher

The OSGi launcher is called from C++ using JNI and it goes like this (details left out for brevity):

```
// Create OSGi framework.
final ServiceLoader<FrameworkFactory> frameworkFactoryLoader =
        ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class);
final FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory =
        getFrameworkFactory(frameworkFactoryLoader);
final Map<String, String> osgiConfig = ...
final Framework osgiFramework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(osgiConfig);

// Start the framework.
osgiFramework.start();

// Install some bundles.
final BundleContext frameworkBundleContext = osgiFramework.getBundleContext();
final Bundle bundle1 =
    installBundle(frameworkBundleContext, "reference:" + bundle1URI, null);
installBundle(frameworkBundleContext, "reference:" + bundle2URI, 5);
installBundle(frameworkBundleContext, "reference:" + bundle3URI, 10);
...

// Explicitly starting a particular bundle.
bundle1.start();
...

// Raise the framework start level so bundles are started
// at the desired start levels.
final FrameworkStartLevel frameworkStartLevelObject =
        bundleAdapt(systemBundle, FrameworkStartLevel.class);
frameworkStartLevelObject.setStartLevel(10, ...left-out...);
```

The helper function for installing a bundle goes like this:

```
private Bundle installBundle(final BundleContext frameworkBundleContext,
                             final String bundleURI,
                             final Integer desiredStartLevel) {
    final Bundle bundle = frameworkBundleContext.installBundle(bundleURI);
    if (desiredStartLevel != null) {
        // Set the level at which the bundle should start.
        // (Otherwise, it will start at the default level.)
        final BundleStartLevel bundleStartLevel =
            bundleAdapt(bundle, BundleStartLevel.class);
        bundleStartLevel.setStartLevel(desiredStartLevel);
    }
}
```

Now, all bundles are resolved and are either in the `RESOLVED`, `ACTIVE` or `STARTED` state.

## Starting with `osgi.clean=true`

If I start the OSGi framework with option `osgi.clean=true` in the `osgiConfig` map and change the bundles installed from run to run that is nicely reflected in the framework.

If I e.g. start the framework with bundleX and bundleY and call

```
frameworkBundleContext.getBundles();
```

then I see exactly

- The system bundle (`ACTIVE`)
- bundleX (`RESOLVED`)
- bundleY (`RESOLVED`)

If I shut down the program and retry this time with bundleX and bundleZ then I see (no surprise)

- The system bundle (`ACTIVE`)
- bundleX (`RESOLVED`)
- bundleZ (`RESOLVED`)

## Starting without `osgi.clean`

If I start the OSGi framework *without* setting `osgi.clean` in the `osgiConfig` map then installed bundles stick around from run to run and new bundles are not resolved.

So assume that I run one time with `osgi.clean=true` loading bundleX and bundleY and then shut down the program.

Now, when I and restart without `osgi.clean` and install only bundleZ, then I see:

- The system bundle (`ACTIVE`)
- bundleX (`RESOLVED`)
- bundleY (`RESOLVED`)
- bundleZ (`INSTALLED`) (i.e. not resolved yet)

So bundleX and bundleY survived from one run to another without having to be installed the 2nd time.

On the other hand, bundleZ does not resolve automatically. To get it  to the `RESOLVED` state I need to do this:

```
  final FrameworkWiring frameworkWiring = systemBundle.adapt(FrameworkWiring.class);
  frameworkWiring.resolveBundles(null);
```

## Question: Should I use `osgi.clean` or not?

It seems that using `osgi.clean=true` gives me a fresh start every time, whereas not using it means that bundle state survives from run to run. I guess the caching makes OSGi start faster but it does not seem to be a big deal for me (as I install the bundles using the "reference:" prefix which means the jars are not copied to the cache, only a reference to the original file location is kept).

However, my application is a multi process application running against the same OSGi configuration area. Is it a problem running with `osgi.clean=true` all the time in this situation?

Also, if somebody could point me to a good explanation of exactly what `osgi.clean` means and how caching in OSGi (Equinox) works I would appreciate it.

Comment: I updated the question with details about start levels.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore `osgi.clean`. Also please ignore start levels. The step you're missing is actually starting your bundles!

Each call to `installBundle` gives you a `Bundle` object. After installing all the bundles, you should then call `start()` on each of the returned bundle objects.

Any other way that you have been using to start bundles has been down to pure luck, i.e. because those bundles might once have been started and cached in that state. The same state would probably not be repeatable if you installed the application on another machine. So actually take control of your bundles and start them yourself.

You usually don't need to worry about the difference between INSTALLED and RESOLVED. Installed can simply mean "not resolved *yet*", e.g. because the bundle's exports weren't needed. If there are any resolving problems such as missing dependencies, then you will find out about them as `BundleException` when calling the `start` method.

Comment: If I ignore `osgi.clean`, old previously installed bundles will automatically be installed. So I will need `osgi.clean` at least when I change the configuration to not load specific bundles, to make Equinox forget them. Regarding the "pure luck" statement, what I left out is that I carefully set the desired `startlevel` for each bundle (to control start order) and also explicitly start one bundle that won't start itself `/org.eclipse.equinox.console`). AFAIK, that is exactly what the Eclipse launcher and the `org.eclipse.equinox.simpleonfigurator` both do. bundle3 in the example is a fragment.

Comment: I updated the original question with details about start levels.

Comment: However, setting start levels doesn't actually cause bundles to be start. They still need to be explicitly started -- it's just that if you start a bundle that is above the current start level, then it will not actually get activated yet. HOWEVER... why are you messing with start levels at all? You hardly ever need to do this!

Comment: Also... please, please don't look at the Eclipse launcher and simpleconfigurator from p2 as any kind of "good practice" example in OSGi.